# Can't get data from ajax to controller, Error: Undefined index: dataId

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

So what I want to do here is when I click a button(with id) it will redirect me to a page according to its id. But my error is undefined index: dataId

This is the ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".btn-clinic").click(function(){
    var dataId = $(this).data("id");
    var baseUrl = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>clinic/getId";
    
    alert("The data-id of clicked item is: " + dataId);

    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:baseUrl,
    dataType:'json',
    data:{'dataId': dataId},
    cache:false,

    success:function(data){
    }

    
  });

  });
```

This is my code in my controller

```
  function getId(){


$id = $_POST['dataId'];
if(!empty($id)){
  echo 'not empty' + $id;
}
else{
  echo 'empty data id ';
}
}
```

but the error is [undefined index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h03MD.png)

This is the code of my view

```
foreach($data as $row)
    {

      echo "<div class='card mb-4'>";
        echo "<div class='row g-0'>";
           echo "<div class='col-md-4'>";
               echo "<img src='...' alt='...'>
            </div>";
            echo "<div class='col-md-8'>";
              echo "<div class='card-body'>";
                   echo "<h5 class='card-title'>".$row->clinicname."</h5>";
                   echo "<p class='card-text'>".$row->clinicname."</p>";
                   echo "<p class='card-text'><small class='text-muted'>".$row->clinicaddress."</small></p>";
                   echo "<a id='clinic' href=";?><?php echo base_url(). "clinic";?> <?php echo "value=".$row->clinicid." class='btn-clinic d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm btn-primary shadow-sm' data-id=".$row->clinicid."><i class='fas fa-download fa-sm text-white-50'></i> See more</a>";
                echo "</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>";
    
    }
```

Comment: href should be "#" other wise it will redirect to some other page.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do, I have a file named clinic.php where I can just fetch the data from the model according to the value of the id of the button that was clicked. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a jquery version having a version greater or equal to 1.5, you have to replace "**type**" with "**method**" this way.

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    URL: baseUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {'dataId': dataId},
    cache: false,
    success:function(data){
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm using jquery-3.4.1. with type. The docs say: **"*Type: An alias for method. You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.*"** It doesn't say that you have to replace type with method at all!